# How to show Select box Options on Button Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the Select Box Options on button. Not on the Select Box Dropdown. When i click on the button the Dropdown List will show up.

***UPDATED***
I mean. When click on dropdown box the confirmation box will show. Then when i click on cancel nothing show up.. When i click on OK the dropdown list will show up.

Here is my code

```
<select id="mySelect" name="myselect" onclick="myFunction()">
<option value="Audi">Audi
<option value="BMW">BMW
<option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
<option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
   var txt;
   var select=document.getElementsByName("myselect");
   var r = confirm("Press a button!");
   if (r == true) {
      select.show();
      txt = "You pressed OK!";
   } else {
      txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
   }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
  }
   </script>
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve here; `select` elements already act like buttons that open drop-down lists. Are you trying to write a list that doesn't have selectable options? (In that case, you would want to use list tags like `ol`, `ul`, and `li`.)

Comment: No No .. I mean. When click on dropdown box the confirmation box will show. Then when i click on cancel nothing show up.. When i click on OK the dropdown will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
function myFunction(item) {
   var txt;
   var dropDown=document.getElementsByName("myselect");
   var r = confirm("Press a button!");
   if (r == true) {      
     item.setAttribute("size", item.options.length);
      txt = "You pressed OK!";
   } else {
     
      txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
   }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
  }
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" name="myselect" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<option value="Audi">Audi
<option value="BMW">BMW
<option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
<option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to mimic your intended functionality exactly; displaying a synchronous `confirm` dialog seems to take the focus off of the `select` element. However, I was able to make it so that you can open the select once yourself *after* saying OK to the dialog.

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo'), ignore = false

document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('focus', function () {
  if (ignore) {
    ignore = false
  } else if (confirm('Press a button!')) {
    demo.textContent = 'You pressed OK!'
    ignore = true
  } else {
    demo.textContent = 'You pressed Cancel!'
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" name="myselect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>
```